# R Time Series horizon doesn't reach the the end date of my data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have continuous daily data from 2015-12-01 to 2016-07-01.Since it's already been aggregated, these are unique dates with correspondent quantity. 
However, whenever i convert the data into time series using ts() and plot.ts() it. The potting shows my tseries never reach 2016-07-01, but only stops around 2016-0. While ggplot of df data shows the ideal graph.

df

[image: df]

```
       tseries = ts(df$F, start = c(2015,12,01), end = c(2016,07,01), frequency = 208)
       plot.ts(tseries)
```

tseries
[image: tseries]

dfplotting
[image: df plotting]

Comment: Could you add the data as text? (so we can copy-paste and help)

Comment: what does `frequency = 208` mean?

Comment: @Bulat, it's the total number of observation from 2015-12-01 to 2016-07-01. I also have a tough time to figure out the right frequency... I tried many numbers, but only 208 seems right... at least on the plotting

Comment: @Devin There's a misconception about the `frequency` argument. Please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** You misspecified the `frequency` (and `start`) arguments in `ts`; either provide correct `frequency`/`start` arguments, or use the `zoo` package instead.

---

There is a misunderstanding about the role of `frequency` in `ts`. The frequency argument depends on the format of your data. For example, if you have daily data for a year then `frequency` would be 365, since one year has 365 days (ignoring leap years). `start` then has to match the `frequency` of your data. For daily data, `start` needs to provide the day (out of 365) of your start date.

Let's generate a date sequence from 01/12/2015 until 01/07/2016 in 1 day steps.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015/12/01"), as.Date("2016/07/01"), by = "1 day")
```

Next we generate some sample data for every day.

```
set.seed(2017);
x <- 100 - cumprod(1 + rnorm(length(dates), 0.01, 0.05))
```

We create a `ts` object and plot.

```
tseries <- ts(
    x,
    start = c(2015, as.numeric(format(dates[1], "%j"))),
    frequency = 365)
plot.ts(tseries);
```

[image]

Note how `as.numeric(format(dates[1], "%j"))` is the day of the year that corresponds to the 01/12/2015; we can inspect `tseries` to confirm

```
tseries;
#Time Series:
#Start = c(2015, 335)
#End = c(2016, 183)
#Frequency = 365
#  [1] 98.91829 98.91165 98.86055 98.94935 98.94251 98.90804 99.00404 98.99416
#  [9] 98.99744 98.90906 98.87945 98.78015 98.81349 98.78344 98.85828 98.77868
# [17] 98.79591 98.70452 98.76475 98.80961 98.78934 98.82882 98.70564 98.79937
# [25] 98.74176 98.72526 98.73731 98.68448 98.72841 98.70941 98.74059 98.71282
# [33] 98.66201 98.71089 98.67883 98.45837 98.52216 98.36389 98.37027 98.37203
# [41] 98.44200 98.42452 98.46624 98.52957 98.53985 98.44419 98.42480 98.33157
# [49] 98.23825 98.11436 97.96746 98.10811 98.07050 98.05331 98.18894 98.26369
# [57] 98.10984 97.95076 97.95309 97.96750 97.86906 97.82784 97.95063 97.92361
# [65] 97.80495 97.75671 97.78848 97.70829 97.60183 97.67609 97.51230 97.57353
# [73] 97.62052 97.79321 97.57016 97.18006 97.25852 97.25187 97.13964 97.10216
# [81] 97.44889 97.22116 97.20823 97.16990 97.13855 97.10450 96.93565 96.79920
# [89] 96.82153 96.84342 96.86261 96.78734 97.08032 97.19380 97.30147 97.21610
# [97] 97.23463 97.39229 97.47829 97.56498 97.53851 97.34443 97.32700 97.18775
#[105] 97.29549 97.53480 97.44546 97.38659 97.23025 97.29599 97.36905 97.38267
#[113] 97.30787 97.36199 97.41452 97.31361 96.98821 96.92238 96.78418 96.87618
#[121] 96.78397 96.79244 96.80496 96.87619 97.00473 96.77162 96.61101 96.91671
#[129] 96.70001 96.75187 96.85348 96.77186 96.59937 96.72491 96.81188 96.80928
#[137] 96.71012 96.39952 96.49581 96.50415 96.56627 96.51843 96.72303 96.59825
#[145] 96.71873 96.65840 96.69296 96.86833 96.79887 96.71224 96.75685 96.76380
#[153] 96.63228 96.74893 96.51374 96.66589 96.61319 96.75718 96.62919 96.39169
#[161] 96.47066 96.59940 96.52173 96.50408 96.22667 96.03279 96.01529 95.80778
#[169] 95.77858 95.90350 96.15438 95.86239 95.99304 95.89340 95.70911 95.74620
#[177] 95.66125 95.81266 95.56044 95.36743 95.35368 95.54013 95.17587 95.07042
#[185] 94.67955 94.57888 94.57412 94.37998 94.36650 93.92591 93.82484 93.71398
#[193] 93.66040 93.60182 93.51263 93.54927 92.93701 92.72238 92.63081 92.85764
#[201] 92.61470 92.28663 92.28687 92.17086 92.31845 92.11827 91.72824 91.78567
#[209] 91.68942 91.34734 90.89702 91.32072 91.11538 90.83474
```

Note that the 335th day of 2015 corresponds to the 1st of December 2015, and the 183rd day of 2016 to the 1st of July 2016.

---

As an alternative we can also use the `zoo` package, which has the benefit that we don't have to work out the proper `frequency` (and `start`) arguments.

```
library(zoo);
tseries <- zoo(x, dates);
plot.zoo(tseries);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Maurits! But i still have a question regarding your tseries plotting, why it still ranges 2015/09 to 2016/05. Should it be from 2015/12/01  to 2016/07/01?

Comment: @Devin `2015.9` is **not** `2015/09`; it's the **decimal year**, and corresponds to day 335 of year 2015 (see the output of `tseries`): `335/365 = 0.9`.

Comment: @Thank you so much! Now i fully understand the reasoning!

Comment: You're very welcome @Devin; please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.